# Autobiographical number in python?

Tags: python, numbers

Hey all at stackoverflow!
I am learning python and need to code a program which checks if a number is autobiographical. EG:
21200 is autobiographical as it has 2 0's 1 1's 2 2's 0 3's and 0 4's. This is what i have so far:

```
# Autobiographical numbers
a = input("Number: ")
abn = 
if a == abn:
  print(a, "is autobiographical")
else:
  print(a, "is not autobiographical")
```

as you can see i have left the abn variable open as i dont know exactly how to do it. I think i have to determine length of a with len(a) then use something like

```
[x[::1] for x in b]
```

but i am not quite sure as i am pretty new to python.
Thanks,
A no0b at python.

Comment: See http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Self-describing_numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following code to test it. There should be a better solution.

```
from collections import Counter
def test(x):
    if len(x) > 10:
           return False
    c = Counter(x)
    for i, v in enumerate(x):
            if int(v) != c.get(str(i), 0):
                    return False
    return True

a = input('number: '): #2.x use raw_input
if test(a):
    print(a, 'is')
else:
    print(a, 'is not')
```

Demo:

```
>>> auto
['1210', '2020', '21200', '3211000', '42101000']
>>> map(test, auto)
[True, True, True, True, True]

>>> auto = ['12321', '13213', '134', '1231', '123124543']
>>> map(test, auto)
[False, False, False, False, False]
```

A much better solution from the wiki:

```
>>> def isSelfDescribing(n):
        s = str(n)
        return all(s.count(str(i)) == int(ch) for i, ch in enumerate(s))
```

Comment: Thanks to all who replied! i loved the help from all of you and i appreciated the link to the site. I gave zhangyangyu first choice because he showed me how to get the desired output in python 3. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As Dmitry [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074329/autobiographical-number-in-python#comment26451296_18074329), Rosettacode has the answer: [Self-describing numbers](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Self-describing_numbers#Python)
:

```py
def isSelfDescribing(n):
    s = str(n)
    return all(s.count(str(i)) == int(ch) for i, ch in enumerate(s))
```

My solution would be the following (despite being slower):

```py
from collections import Counter
def isAutobiographical(n):
    digits = map(int, str(x))
    actualFrequency = Counter(digits)
    claimedFrequency = dict((x,y) for x,y in enumerate(digits) if y > 0)
    return actualFrequency == claimedFrequency
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

b = int(math.log(a,10))

*b is length of a. i.e., number of digits in a*

*in fact there is another tick:*

b = len(str(a))

*of course you need to check if a is a valid natural number*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def is_autobiographical(n):
    s = str(n)
    count_digits = ''.join([str(s.count(str(i))) for i in range(len(s))])
    return s == count_digits

>>> is_autobiographical(21200)
True
>>> is_autobiographical(22)
False
```

In your case you could use `abn = ''.join([str(str(a).count(str(i))) for i in range(len(str(a)))])` to fit your needs.